# Magento exclude Catalog Price Promotions for country

Tags: magento, catalog, promotions

I need to modify magneto promotions for Catalog Price to exclude the for specific IP/Country.. I will do it using geoIP. What I need to help with and cannot figure out yet is howto modify magento code so it will not use the promotion(special) discount(prices). I just cannot find the right file to modify.

Comment: we need to do the same thing. You ever figure this out?